# iOS canOpenURL returns true, but app is not installed(facebook)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, url

Currently, I want to check in my app whether Facebook App is installed or not.

**What am I doing:**

```
UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "fb://")!)enter code here
```

In URL Schemes I have added fb, so not missed that part too.

But canOpenURL RETURNS `TRUE` ! But the app IS UNinstalled. I restarted the device, not helped. Why this is happening?
UPDATE: some code

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "fb://")!) {
    self.shareToFacebook(with: completion)
} else {
    progressVC.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/facebook/id284882215")!)
}
```

SOLUTION: I found the solution people. In URL types I had been added fb45....(id of my app), and also added fb, which one shouldn't be there, I removed fb, and only kept the one with id, so the openURL now returns false if the app is not installed

Comment: if you added that to url schemes app can open, what else do you want it to do?

Comment: Lu_ I want to handle case when Facebook App is not installed, but I get true everytime, even if the app is UNINSTALLED

Comment: and what happens then when app is uninstalled? everything is going like it should

Comment: Lu_ it's trying to share to Facebook, but the app is uninstalled, but I need to redirect the user to App Store

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add `fb` to the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` array in the app plist, not the `URL schemes` array, like so:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fb</string>
</array>
```