# `canOpenURL` returns true for Apple Music app when it was removed from device

Tags: ios, apple-music

**What I want**

Check in my app whether Apple Music app is installed or not. For that I'm using `canOpenURL()` method and validate the result (boolean value).

**Problem:**

If Apple Music app already installed, `canOpenURL()` returns `true`, obviously. But after removing application from the real device, `canOpenURL()` return true as well. But expected result should be `false` ('cause the app isn't installed).

**Additional info**

I'm tested that workflow on iPhone XR, iOS 12.0.

Also, I've added in the Info.plist `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key, where wrote array with different app schemes. It's looks like

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>music</string>
        ....
    </array>
```

URL is next: `URL(string: "audio-player-event://")`. I'm also used another strings, like `music:\\` and `musics:\\`.

I used [this](https://ios.gadgethacks.com/news/always-updated-list-ios-app-url-scheme-names-0184033/) source to get all needed app schemes.

I'm also checked all corresponded questions on the SO (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45607394/ios-canopenurl-returns-true-but-app-is-not-installedfacebook)), but no one has the reasonable answer.

Comment: What URL exactly are you using?

Comment: upd.: added URL in question description

Comment: Well, it's maybe due to the fact that stock Apple apps don't get removed from the system, they are only hidden (and there is a reason for that -- Federighi explains it in a Gruber interview). Nevertheless, I guess it could be easily classified as a bug, so I would file a bug report to Apple and hope that it gets fixed.