# Open social media apps from flutter app using url_launcher

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to redirect from my flutter app to social media platform apps using a profile/business URL. I am using the url_launcher dart package. I was able to find the endpoint to redirect to a Facebook profile but don't know how to open specific Instagram and Twitter pages.

```
_launchFacebook(String? facebook) async {
    final url = 'fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://' + facebook!;
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  _launchTwitter(String? twitter) async {
    final url = 'tw://' + twitter!;
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  _launchInstagram(String? instagram) async {
    final url = 'in://' + instagram!;
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Facebook is a bit of an odd case here, asking for a specific protocol `fb://facewebmodal/f?href=$url`.

Usually, applications register the URL of their website for deep linking, which means they will open in your browser if you don't have the corresponding app installed, and directly in their app if you do.

This is the implementation I usually use, which definitely works for Facebook, Twitter, Instagram and LinkedIn. I included a special check for Android, so that if you don't have Facebook installed, it will open up the link correctly in the browser instead.

```dart
  @override
  Future<void> launchUrl(String url) async {
    final _canLaunch = await canLaunch(url);
    if (kIsWeb) {
      if (_canLaunch) {
        await launch(url);
      } else {
        throw "Could not launch $url";
      }
      return;
    }
    if (TargetPlatform.android) {
      if (url.startsWith("https://www.facebook.com/")) {
        final url2 = "fb://facewebmodal/f?href=$url";
        final intent2 = AndroidIntent(action: "action_view", data: url2);
        final canWork = await intent2.canResolveActivity();
        if (canWork) return intent2.launch();
      }
      final intent = AndroidIntent(action: "action_view", data: url);
      return intent.launch();
    } else {
      if (_canLaunch) {
        await launch(url, forceSafariVC: false);
      } else {
        throw "Could not launch $url";
      }
    }
  }
```

You can without any problem open links in the `https://instagram.com/username` and the `https://twitter.com/username` formats with it.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to do it:

```
Future<void> _launchSocialMediaAppIfInstalled({
  String url,
}) async {
  try {
    bool launched = await launch(url, forceSafariVC: false); // Launch the app if installed!

    if (!launched) {
      launch(url); // Launch web view if app is not installed!
    }
  } catch (e) {
    launch(url); // Launch web view if app is not installed!
  }
}
```

And then simply call it like this:

```
_launchSocialMediaAppIfInstalled(
  url: 'https://www.instagram.com/avey.world/', //Instagram
);

_launchSocialMediaAppIfInstalled(
  url: 'https://www.facebook.com/avey.pal/', // Facebook
);

_launchSocialMediaAppIfInstalled(
  url: 'https://twitter.com/avey_pal', // Twitter
);

_launchSocialMediaAppIfInstalled(
  url: 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/avey-ai/', // Linkedin
);

...
```

Don't forget to replace the example page by yours ;) and that's it!

Comment: This is perfect. It worked!

Comment: This is good but in android what happened ?

Answer (score 1):

You can without any problem open apps directly with web link.

Instagram, twitter, youtube, linkdln and tiktok work perfectly with web link like [https://instagram.com/'username'](https://instagram.com/%27username%27) etc.

Specifically, you can use this link for Facebook : https://facebook.com/profile.php?id=your_id

```
void _launchURL(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(url))) {
      await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url), mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

It's worked for me

```
 launchUrlString('https://www.linkedin.com/');
```